# VB.net 2015 Prevent a second CMD instance to show up

Tags: vb.net

```
        Shell("cmd.exe", AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus)

    Thread.Sleep(50)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("cd c:\users\Administrator\desktop\captcharuc", True)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{Enter}", True)
    Thread.Sleep(50)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("tesseract.exe imagen.jpg leerca -psm 7", True)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{Enter}", True)
    Thread.Sleep(50)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("exit", True)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{Enter}", True)
```

im streaming commands to a CMD instance, everything works fine but when i execute the tesseract.exe another CMD instance opens to execute such program.

this is the regular behavior of tesseract if i do all those steps manually, a second CMD instance will show up to execute the tesseract commands.

this is part of a windows app that im developing and really dont want that second instance to show up.

I have tried with

```
Const strCmdText As String = "/c cd c:\users\Administrator\desktop\captcharuc\&tesseract.exe imagen.jpg leerca -psm 7"
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("CMD.EXE")
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    startInfo.Arguments = strCmdText
    Process.Start(startInfo)
```

and with

```
Shell("cmd /c """ & "cd c:\users\Administrator\desktop\captcharuc\" & "&tesseract.exe imagen.jpg leerca -psm 7" & """", AppWinStyle.Hide, True)
```

in the 3 cases the main instance will either run minimized or hidden as intended but the second instance will bring up the tesseract instance.

would really appreciate if i get some help here as I ran out of ideas on how to prevent such event from happening.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a good night sleep i came up with a solution to the problem, i did create a .bat file like this

```
@Echo off
Set _SourcePath=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\captcharuc\*.jpg
Set _OutputPath=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\captcharuc\
Set _Tesseract="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
For %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting %%A...&%_Tesseract% %%A %_OutputPath%%leerca
Set "_SourcePath="
Set "_OutputPath="
Set "_Tesseract="
```

and then called it with

```
Shell("c:\users\Administrator\desktop\captcharuc\tese.bat", AppWinStyle.Hide)
```

and thats it.. mods feel free to mark this thread as solved. thanks

Comment: it says i can accept my own answer tomorrow, wondering whats with the downvoting at OP? is there something to donw vote here?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, so I couldn't tell you.  Voting is anonymous.